# Fixing "A lock is not available" on Work (SAS)

Tags: sas, locking

I'm working with a complex set of SAS algorithms, created by a group outside of my company, to prepare a report required each year. Unfortunately, I am running into a file lock problem:

> ERROR: A lock is not available for WORK._TEMP_OP_OTHER.DATA

I did have a similar issue last year, but it then appeared to be a somewhat random problem that cropped up (rarely) during execution. I reviewed the logs to see if the problem occurred, and if so cleaned up the output files and ran the algorithm again.

This year's report is consistently producing the error in the same place every time I run the algorithm. I have tried a couple of things to give the system more time in the hopes that the lock will become available: inserting  a SLEEP command and also setting FILELOCKWAIT=n in libname statements. Neither has worked as I'd hoped.

FILELOCKWAIT seems like the most promising option, but when observing the execution of the algorithm and reviewing the logs it's clear that the process is failing immediately at that section, consistent with the default FILELOCKWAIT value of 0 seconds.

I am far from an expert in SAS, but I am wondering if I need to set FILELOCKWAIT for WORK, as that is where the lock issue is coming up. Is there a way to do this, and might it help my problem? If not, are there other options I could look into?

(Note: I am aware of the TRYLOCK macro, but want to introduce as few changes as possible to the algorithms I'm running. As mentioned above, they are complex and I am concerned about introducing unintended problems which may be difficult to notice, diagnose, and fix).

Comment: If the file is locked, this would be because another process still has it opened with member-level control. Is this a single, serial SAS process, or are there multiple concurrent processes occurring in which one of them is writing to or accessing this file while others are trying to access it?

Comment: @StuSztukowski It's just this one process, which creates the WORK directory and then updates it (as far as I can tell from my investigation thus far). It's possible that the macro is doing something more complex than I realize, but this is a major release from a large research group and should run as written (and as it has worked in previous years). The section of code that is failing is unchanged from last year's release.

Comment: Interesting... These can be tough to figure out. If you add `options mprint mlogic symbolgen macrogen;` you'll be able to see what the macro is doing in great detail as it steps through. If you add these options and run it, are you able to backtrack from the point it produces the error and see when the dataset was accessed prior to the error? I have one other suggestion that you can try but it must be used very carefully as it opens up datasets with record-level control rather than member-level control.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I've got those options on, and can find every point where that dataset was accessed. But my SAS is rusty enough that I'm not sure what to look for in terms of releasing the lock.

Comment: Got it. Second question: Are you running this through Enterprise Guide 8.x by chance?

Comment: @StuSztukowski No, it's SAS 9.4

Comment: FILELOCKWAIT should not be needed for WORK.  WORK is unique to the running session, so there should be no contention with other (if any) SAS sessions.  Are you running DS2 code with threads ? Sort or Stat procedures with threads ? Any SYSTASK calls ?  Is the data set involved with any ODS reporting ?

Comment: @Richard No stat procedures. There is a sort procedure called on the data set experiencing the lock issue prior to the point where the error occurs. I do not believe there is any DS2 code in the algorithm. There does seem to be ODS reporting as well.

Comment: How large are the tables  being worked with ? You could try some OS resource monitoring during a runtime and hope to get a locked scenario (sounds like it is repeatable) .  There may be high contention at write times, some issues with disk buffering, disk space or even disk issues found in SMART information.  SAS SORT uses threads.

Comment: @Richard I'm not certain how large the tables on WORK are, but the relevant output table is six columns and just under one million rows, so reasonably large but not enormous. OS resource monitoring is a good idea, though I may need to reach out to my IT department to get that information.